# prime ng autocomplete input field reset when user click outside

Tags: angular

When we give forceSelection property to true in primeng autocomplete.
then if we enter values manually and selected any option after clicking outside the selected option gets reset,
please help someone with this.

```
 <p-autoComplete [required]="true"  (keydown.entry)="commonService.showSuggestion($event,endPointType)"  [(ngModel)]="endPoint.externalSystemNameAndVersion" [suggestions]="externalSystemList" (completeMethod)="fetchExternalSystemList($event)" [forceSelection]="true" [minLength]="1"></p-autoComplete >
```

I tried to keydown. entry is working fine after selecting the option to press enter.
but I need it when clicking outside the data should not reset.